# Microsoft SQL Server; Selecting SUBSTRING (FIXED LENGTH)

Tags: sql-server, substring, fixed

I'm kind of a beginner when it comes to SQL; I've got the following problem.

I need to return a string-value (containing 10 characters) from one of my columns. However, this column is full of garbage characters (i.e. non-usable)

Rows within the column look like this (data has been anonamized):

2014-08-22 06:02:58.552: XXen: AAAAXXXXXXXbcod5fhuTGPfptufSLUp5MtVHbXuVSFkW8LJfdFkbYg==]  2014-08-22 06:02:59.417: Fetch customer profile success. **XXNUMBER: 2xxxxxx1**. ASDLJASDLKxxxx aksjdlXxx1213: 123111

This is followed by more useless characters.

Thus, the string contains all kinds of characters; the part I'm looking for is 'XXNumber: 2xxxxxx1', where I need to return '2xxxxxx1'. The length of this number is fixed (8 characters).

Any idea how to do this (I'm SQL Management Studio),

Much obliged,

Steven

PS: I'm guessing some sort of SUBSTRING command, but I'm kinda lost in oblivion.

Comment: how can this be both mysql and sql-server

Comment: You´re right, my bad; wanted to select as much tags but they should be relevant ;)!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with SUBSTRING() and CHARINDEX().  For example:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX) = '2014-08-22 06:02:58.552: XXen: AAAAXXXXXXXbcod5fhuTGPfptufSLUp5MtVHbXuVSFkW8LJfdFkbYg==] 2014-08-22 06:02:59.417: Fetch customer profile success. XXNUMBER: 2xxxxxx1. ASDLJASDLKxxxx aksjdlXxx1213: 123111'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('XXNUMBER:',@string,1)+10,8)
```

Returns:

> 2xxxxxx1

The +10 in the select is the length of the string for XXNUMBER.

Comment: Thanks for your reply;

The query you've suggested does provide me with some output; sadly not the right output.

The problem here is that the declared @string has a variable length, i.e. it can contain approximately 300 to 400 characters.

Moreover, the # of characters preceding XXNumber is variable, as well as the # of characters succeeding 2xxxxxx1 (gladly this part is fixed as I allready mentioned).

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: My formula meets your requirements - I was just showing you an example by providing your example as a variable.  Just change the variable to your field name: `SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldname, CHARINDEX('XXNUMBER:',fieldname,1)+10,8) FROM tablename`

Answer (score 0):

The folling query provides us with the desired output:

select substring((SUBSTRING(columnname, CHARINDEX('xxnumber', columnname), 18)),11,8) as xxnumber from dbo.xxx

Thanks for your initial reply, it gave us the perspective needed to solve the problem at hand!